# `Refl` thing in Calculus of Constructions?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, equality, dependent-type, morte

In languages such as `Agda`, `Idris`, or `Haskell` with type extensions, there is a `=` type sort of like the following

```
data a :~: b where
  Refl :: a :~: a
```

`a :~: b` means that `a` and `b` are the same.

Can such a type be defined in the [calculus of constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions) or [Morte](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Morte-Library) (which is programming language based on the calculus of construction)?

Comment: Every inductive type can be encoded in CoC, but with no associated _dependent_ elimination principle (non-dependent elimination is available). (Also note that `a :~: b` is a type, but `Refl` is a value.)

Comment: Calculus of constructions is the "top" of the lambda cube. Haskell,Agda and Idris are "below" CoC. Hence it ought to be possible for the simple fact that CoC is more expressive.  (Someone could point out if I'm wrong in this deduction?)

Comment: @Bakuriu Actually, Agda/Coq are beyond CoC since they also allow inductive types with dependent elimination, which CoC lacks. Agda also proves Streicher's axiom K, which implies that that any two proofs `p,q` of the same equality `a=b` must be equal (`p=q`) -- unavailable in CoC or Coq (aka CiC).

Comment: @chi: I should also note impredicative `Prop` in Coq and induction-recursion in Agda and Idris as features going far beyond the lambda cube.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Interesting. Isn't `*` impredicative in CoC, though?

Comment: @chi Do you have a resource explaining dependent elimination? (I had trouble looking it up.)

Comment: I found [this](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~lebresne/papers/CodingDependentElimination.pdf). Surely some type theory books describe non-dependent vs dependent elimination, but I can not access them right now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard Church-encoding of `a :~: b` in CoC is:

```
(a :~: b) =
   forall (P :: * -> * -> *).
      (forall c :: *. P c c) ->
      P a b
```

`Refl` being

```
Refl a :: a :~: a
Refl a =
   \ (P :: * -> * -> *)
     (h :: forall (c::*). P c c) ->
     h a
```

The above formulates equality between *types*. For equality between *terms*, the `:~:` relation must take an additional argument `t :: *`, where `a b :: t`.

```
((:~:) t a b) = 
   forall (P :: t -> t -> *).
      (forall c :: t. P c c) ->
      P a b

Refl t a :: (:~:) t a a
Refl t a =
   \ (P :: t -> t -> *)
     (h :: forall (c :: t). P c c) ->
     h a
```

Comment: Intriguing. Is it possible to derive a contradiction from `0 :~: 1`, like you can do in the other languages? (Oh wait, I see how. Just make a equality function that returns `()` instead of True and `Void` instead of false. I think that would work.)

Comment: (Also, I see how this easily generalizes to other GADTs.)

Comment: @PyRulez Yes. With church numerals, `0 f x = x` and `1 f x = f x` (modulo additional type arguments). Using that, you can have `0 (const True) False = False` and `1 (const True) False = True`. Assuming `0 :~: 1` and taking `P x y = (x (const True) False) <-> (y (const True) False)`, we can prove `False <-> True`.

Answer (score 1):

```
id : \/a : *. a -> a
id = \a : *. \x : a. x

eqn : \/a : *. a -> a -> *
eqn = \a : *. \x : a. \y : a. \/p : (a -> *). p x -> p y

refl : \/a : *. \/x : a. eqn a x x
refl = \a : *. \x : a. \p : (a -> *). id (p x)
```

where `\/` is the pi-constructor and `\`is the lambda-constructor.

I think that the idea of Church-Scott Encoding is to define a type as its elimination rule and its constructors as its introduction rules.

`either` is a good example:

```
either : * -> * -> *
either = \a : *. \b : *. \/r : *. (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> r 

left : \/a : *. \/b : *. a -> either a b
left = \a : *. \b : *. \x : a. \r : *. \left1 : (a -> r). \right1 : (b -> r). left1 x

right : \/a : *. \/b : *. b -> either a b
right = \a : *. \b : *. \y : b. \r : *. \left1 : (a -> r). \right1 : (b -> r). right1 y
```

`either` is defined as the elimination rule of disjunction.

By this idea, `eqn a x y` must be defined as the liebniz rule `\/p : (a -> *). p x -> p y`, because the elimination rule of equation is the liebniz rule.

---

+) a proof of `1 != 0`:

```
bottom : *
bottom = \/r : *. r

nat : *
nat = \/r : *. r -> (r -> r) -> r

zero : nat
zero = \r : *. \z : r. \s : (r -> r). z

succ : nat -> nat
succ = \n : nat. \r : *. \z : r. \s : (r -> r). s (n r z s)

id : \/a : *. a -> a
id = \a : *. \x : a. x

eqn : \/a : *. a -> a -> *
eqn = \a : *. \x : a. \y : a. \/p : (a -> *). p x -> p y

refl : \/a : *. \/x : a. eqn a x x
refl = \a : *. \x : a. \p : (a -> *). id (p x)

goal : eqn nat (succ zero) zero -> bottom
goal = \one_is_zero : (\/p : (nat -> *). p (succ zero) -> p zero). \r : *. one_is_zero (\n : nat. n * r (\a : *. r -> a)) (id r)
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation? Please see here [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: What do you need `id` for?

Comment: @PyRulez Just for the beauty

Comment: Okay. Is this definition symmetric?

Comment: @PyRulez Yes, it is. To show that definition is symmetric, it is sufficient to derive `a : *`, `x : a`, `y : a` |- `eqn a x y -> eqn a y x`. Let `h : eqn a x y` be given. Since `eqn a x y` == `\/p : (a -> *). p x -> p y`, we can derive `eqn a x x -> eqn a y x` from `h : \/p : (a -> *). p x -> p y`, putting `p` := `\z : a. eqn a z x`. Applying `refl a x : eqn a x x`, we obtain a proof of `eqn a y x`. Q.E.D.