# How to represent arbitrary GADTs on Morte?

Tags: haskell, idris, gadt, morte

Expressing normal data types such as lists and nats is straightforward and there are many examples around. What is the generic procedure to translate GADTs, though? Some examples translating typical types such as Vector and dependent products from Idris to Morte would be very illustrative.

Comment: Second that on dependent products.

Comment: @paulotorrens it is on the Sol repository, I called it [Some](https://github.com/MaiaVictor/Sol/blob/master/book/Some.sol) and [Some.like](https://github.com/MaiaVictor/Sol/blob/master/book/Some.like.sol).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36182693/1172541 for an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get eliminators that depend on elements of data types, but you can define eliminators that depend on indices of elements of data types. Hence, `Vector`s are representable (the code is in Agda):

```
Nat = (P : Set) -> (P -> P) -> P -> P

zero : Nat
zero = λ P f z -> z

suc : Nat -> Nat
suc = λ n P f z -> f (n P f z) 

plus : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
plus = λ n m P f z -> n P f (m P f z)

Vec = λ (A : Set) (n : Nat) ->
  (P : Nat -> Set) -> (∀ n -> A -> P n -> P (suc n)) -> P zero -> P n

nil : ∀ A -> Vec A zero
nil = λ A P f z -> z

cons : ∀ A n -> A -> Vec A n -> Vec A (suc n)
cons = λ A n x xs P f z -> f n x (xs P f z)

concat : ∀ A n m -> Vec A n -> Vec A m -> Vec A (plus n m)
concat = λ A n m xs ys P f z -> xs (λ n -> P (plus n m)) (λ n -> f (plus n m)) (ys P f z)
```

These are very similar to Church-encoded lists, you just make a type, that you eliminate into, dependent on the indices of a data type being defined and change induction hypotheses to reflect the structure of the constructors of the data type. I.e. you have

```
cons : ∀ A n -> A -> Vec A n -> Vec A (suc n)
```

so the corresponding induction hypothesis is

```
∀ n -> A -> P n -> P (suc n)
```

In order to define dependent pairs without inductive types, you need very/[insanely dependent types](https://github.com/UlfNorell/insane) (sigmas are [here](https://github.com/UlfNorell/insane/blob/master/Sigma.agda)), which allow the result of a function depend on this same function being defined. Morte doesn't have this, of course.

Comment: Wow, does this mean that Haskell GADTs are in fact representable?

Comment: @András Kovács, it seems so. I'm a bit surprised too, so can't make strong claims. And not just GADTs, but also GADTs with DataKinds.

Comment: @AndrásKovács I think the main difference between GADTs and this encoding is that pattern matching with GADTs will add a type equality constraint `T ~ S` to the environment, and the type checker then automatically does its job up-to `~`. Instead, with dependent types, even if you have a hypothesis `T=S`, you have to eliminate it manually in the "right" way to to make the rest of your term to type check. The Hasochism paper shows this on a few cases. Because of this, I wouldn't say GADTs are exactly represented, since the representations don't really eliminate like true GADTs.

Comment: @chi, when you pattern match in a dependently typed setting (at the top level), you don't get `T = S `, instead the context is silently rewritten by `T ~ S` just like in Haskell. The difference is that in Haskell `(~)` is a first-class thing, so you can write `a ~ b => c`, while in Agda/Morte/whatever, there are no explicit equality constraints, but they are still presented implicitly. In the encoding above everything is already rewritten and there is nothing to "reveal by pattern matching".

Comment: @chi, also see the answer to [Pattern matching in Observational Type Theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957229/pattern-matching-in-observational-type-theory).

Comment: I fiddled around a bit and I'm quite sure all GHC 7.8 GADTs are representable. Type-indexed GADTs can be rewritten to type-code indexed ones. The GADT propositional equality becomes Leibniz equality, and we also have all the GHC 7.8 singletons with `toSing` and `fromSing`.

Comment: Yes, probably I was still thinking about Coq, where equality must be handled in a different way. E.g. `Definition f (A: Type) (h: A=nat) (g: nat->bool) (x: A): bool := match h with eq_refl => g x end` does not type check. In Agda (with pattern matching at the definition level) it would.

Comment: I still don't quite understand exactly what inductive types mean, but I spent half of my dreams this night puzzled about @AndrásKovács's answer lol. Turns out all I had missing was the `n:Nat` argument inside the Cons constructor, I was using the outer `n` and it didn't work. Still not obvious to me how to translate arbitrary GADTs to Morte, though, but Vector and other types from Idris are working fine and I'm starting to see the pattern. Thank you all :)

Comment: @AndrásKovács do you know of any particular GADT that shouldn't be representable?

Comment: @chi do you still recommend the paper from Lindley & McBride?

Comment: @MaiaVictor: Currently I think all GHC 7.8 GADTs are representable, and also some extra, because we can index by GADTs as well, so we can iterate singleton construction. In about a day when I'll have time I'll rewrite my answer to include more detailed explanation on how to encode arbitrary GHC 7.8 GADTs.

Comment: @András Kovács, I think [direct encoding](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Lists/ChurchVector.agda) of equality is not Leibniz equality, but is isomorphic to it. Though, this is perhaps the usual parameters vs indices dichotomy.

Comment: @MaiaVictor After the discussion, I am no longer sure if that's relevant to the actual question at hand.

Comment: @user3237465 yes, we get Leibniz eq. from the Paulin-Mohring definition with one parameter and one index.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer instead as the other didn't age very well. Indeed any datatype can be represented with Church encodings. But you still can't have the induction principle, just plain iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Everything that is representable is documented in the [Morte tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/morte-1.6.4/docs/Morte-Tutorial.html). GADTs and (more generally) indexed types aren't there, and indeed they aren't possible.

(EDIT: GADTs can be in fact represented; see other answer by user3237465)

The `Vector` type itself can be encoded, but its values aren't usable for much. A `Vector n A` is an `n`-nested pair of `A`-s:

```
Unit   = \(A : *) -> A -> A
Pair   = \(A B : *) -> (P : *) -> (A -> B -> P) -> P
Nat    = (N : *) -> (N -> N) -> N -> N
Vector = \(n : Nat)(A : *) -> n * (\(t : *) -> Pair A t) Unit
```

But writing any useful function for `Vector n A` would require induction on its `n` length, but Morte has no inductive types.

To be clear, by induction I mean that for a certain type a function corresponding to the principle of structural induction is derivable. These are generalizations of folds where the output type may depend on the input value. For some natural number type `Nat : *` with `suc : Nat -> Nat` and `zero : Nat` induction has the following type:

```
natInd : 
      (N : Nat -> *)                   -- a predicate,
   -> ((n : Nat) -> N n -> N (suc n))  -- if it's preserved by suc
   -> N zero                           -- and holds for zero,
   -> (n : Nat) -> N n                 -- holds for every Nat
```

While folding over a `Vector`, the type changes along with the length (since the former depends on the latter). However, with Church `Nat` we only have non-dependent fold (aka "recursion") instead of possibly type-changing fold (aka "induction").

Comment: By the discussion on the other answer, should I assume that, in fact, GADTs _can_ be represented?

Comment: @paulotorrens Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As an example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36182693/1172541) shows how to write the `Refl` type.

Let's say we want to build a simple DSL. Here's how to do ti:

```
Expr t = forall (E :: * -> *). forall
    (IntLit :: Integer -> E Integer),
    (IntVar :: Char -> E Integer),
    (Add :: E Integer -> E Integer -> E Integer),
    (Mult :: E Integer -> E Integer -> E Integer),
    (Neg :: E Integer -> E Integer),
    (IntEq :: E Integer -> E Integer -> E Bool),
    (Lt :: E Integer -> E Integer -> E Bool),
    (And :: E Bool -> E Bool -> E Bool),
    (Or :: E Bool -> E Bool -> E Bool),
    (Not :: E Bool -> E Bool),
    (If :: (forall x :: *. E Bool -> E x -> E x -> E x)).
    E t
```